# Javascript: object expected on line 1 char 2

Tags: javascript, object

http://pastie.org/856698

Anyone have any idea why the script is causing this error?

Comment: By the way, I know 'innerHTML' was spelt wrong on one line; this was not the problem.

Comment: Still fairly new to jquery, just wondering what this error could possibly be. But like I said, the error only seems to show up in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Check your jQuery file to see if you don't have extra characters in there. That is the first referenced script and your error doesn't give a file.

UPDATE:
I'm not getting any errors on your site in IE8 until I press submit. Then it tells me `regSubmit()` is not an object, and indeed it isn't, your function is called `submitReg()`. Perhaps the reason you are getting errors "in IE" is simply because without a debugger loaded, non-IE browsers tend to just skip errors, whereas IE stops processing and puts up a notification.

Try installing Firebug or using Chrome, CTRL+SHIFT+J and watch and see if you get errors there now (you will if you watch the console, but processing will continue anyway).

Comment: The error only appears to be in IE, not firefox.

Reference: http://www.proskimboarding.com/codingtest/Public/registration.php